# Is there a functional reason to prefer a Javascript class with only static methods or a file with functions?

Tags: javascript, function, class

Let's say I've created a class with only static methods like below.

```
export class JWT {
  static getPayload(token: string): { [key: string]: any } {
    ...
  }

  static isExpired(token: string): boolean {
   ...
  }
}
```

I've seen libraries with classes like the above. But given all the class methods are static, there's no shared state amongst the functions. Why not instead create a file named jwt.ts with the same functions but no class?

```
export function getPayload(token: string): { [key: string]: any } {
    ...
  }

export function isExpired(token: string): boolean {
   ...
  }
```

I could call

```
import { JWT } from 'file1';
import { getPayload } from 'file2';
Option 1: JWT.getPayload()
Option 2: getPayload()
```

Is there a functional difference or is this primarily a stylistic difference?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Comment: Using a class that doesn't ever reference `this` doesn't make any sense IMO. A class is when you want to tie together persistent data with methods that operate on that data. If you can refactor to standalone functions while keeping the call signatures the same, that sounds like a class isn't doing anything but adding baggage - JS isn't Java

Comment: In my opinion, they make sense, they work like namespaces and help organizing code and ideas. You can create more files and make them the namespace, which is not exactly better than creating more classes in a single file.

Also, you might have several getPayload functions on your project. but with different implementations depending on your needs. You can separate them in different classes/namespaces. 

Typescript has a namespace feature that can be used.

Comment: One other reason is intelissense. Think that there is a function that you don't remember the name exactly. You Type "JWT." then the intelisse will give you optins that you might can use.